# Rails how to prefill a form that is located on another website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How is it possible to prefill inputfields in a form with data from a database?

Example:
In my database I have name, age and gender

The form that is on a website have the same input fields and the names are name, age and gender.

A user click on link which goes to another website and the inputfields are automatic filled out.

How do I send the information in my database to prefill the input fields on the other website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make your application type things into a web form that you don't control.  If you do control the web form, you could of course make it accept parameters for those values and fill them in when the form is constructed.

You can construct a POST to the other site that would be the equivalent of filling in AND SUBMITTING the form, but that won't show the fields to the user and allow them to edit; it would skip past that step.  Also that might very well be prevented if the external site has security in place to prevent cross-site request forgery.